# How to installing eUML2 free-version in Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, uml, licensing

I need to do some UML diagrams, and doing the work right in Eclipse by reverse engineering classes is the best/fastest approach for me.  Taking advise found elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I'm playing with eUML2.

The problem I have is this...  I installed the Studio demo, and it worked well for us.  However, for now, I just need to do the class diagrams which are available in the free edition.  So I uninstalled the studio demo, and installed the free.  However, it still thinks I have the studio demo installed as the background of my diagrams has it in 24pt font, and in the top right of the page it says "* Evaluation *".

Reading around, I assume this issue is around the problem with the license file contained in the install of the free version... or the fact that it is missing from the free version.

Anyone here figured out the license file issue with eUML2?  Where can I find a free license, or an install with the free license in it?  Where is the license stored in my install?  can I just kill it?

I could ask this question on the Soyatec forum, however this question has been asked a number of times, with no answers provided.  Either they do not monitor their forums, or one must pay the 100€ price for support to get an answer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The studio license is installing a file in your folder user/.eclipse/configuration/... If you erase this file then the tool will consider it is a new install of the software.

Having said that I would not recommend to use eUML because it is full of bugs and adding UML tags in your code. A real mess mixing code and model !!

Comment: That's where the license file was... however just deleting it did not work as it came back on the next restart of Eclipse.  Turns out I had to delete it, uninstall eUML2, delete all Soyatec named files from all the Eclipse folders, reinstall the free version, work through the errors, uninstall again, delete files again, delete my project I had created a UML in, reinstall (with no errors this time!), and recreate the project... NOW I have UMLs without big evaluation messages... whew!  Although, on little feature of the free version.  The diagrams do not have "instantiate" lines.  :(

Answer (score 1):

For your information it seems to me that it is intentional not to answer to any question and stop the Soyatec company. 
Don't forget that Soyatec is more or less a kind of Omondo spin off. 4 shareholders having created the omondo company left it with the code of EclipseUML 2005. I know that the tool is now totally different because being revamped by a new team but the architecture is still more or less the same.

Omondo Corp is currently being under acquisition by a large US software company and once the sell will completed it could be possible that they claim redundancy package, or company shares etc... to the main shareholder who sacked them few years ago. They have a split contract but it seems that it is not valid.

Just money, always money. This world is disguising :-)

Comment: nice... way to kill a product.